# How to use IO in a raw serving handler?

Tags: haskell, servant

I use servant 0.19, so no the type `RawM`. I have a handler:

```hs
hnd :: Something -> ServerT Raw Handler
hnd Something {..} = do
  -- p <- readIORef somePath -- COULDN'T MATCH TYPE "IO b0" WITH "Tagged Handler Application"
  let stSet = defaultFileServerSettings "a/b/c"
  serveDirectoryWith stSet
```

which is described as an API's type: `:<|> "some" :> Raw`

I want to do IO operations in my `hnd` handler. How to do it with this servant version (without `RawM`)? Also, I'd be grateful if you show it with `RawM` too (though it is not important due to the used version 0.19).

Comment: If the `ServerT Raw Handler` is an instance of `MonadIO`, you can wrap the action in `liftIO`

Comment: whole `do`: `liftIO $ do ...`? What is the type of this handler then? `Handler Raw`? I get a type mismatch error: "Tagged m0 Application" with `IO Raw` (expected `IO Raw`).

Comment: no, the `IO a` thing you want to "lift".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer.  Try:

```
hnd :: Something -> ServerT Raw Handler
hnd Something{..} = Tagged $ \req resp -> do
  p <- readIORef somePath
  let stSet = defaultFileServerSettings p
  staticApp stSet req resp
```

The longer answer is that `ServerT` is a type family associated with the `HasServer` type class that maps API expressions to transformations of the `Handler` monad to implement the API `:>` and `:<|>` combinators as well as individual endpoints.  For a "normal" endpoint, like `Get`, it maps the type `ServerT (Get ...) Handler` to plain old `Handler`.

To implement `Raw`, `ServerT Raw Handler` is mapped to `Tagged Handler Application`.  This is simply a WAI `Application` whose type has been `Tagged` with the `Handler` monad.

Servant-supplied wrappers, like `serveDirectoryWith`, are really just WAI `Application`s that have been `Tagged`:

```
serveDirectoryWith :: StaticSettings -> ServerT Raw m
serveDirectoryWith = Tagged . staticApp
```

where `staticApp` is the underlying static file serving `Application` from the `wai-app-static` package.

So, that means that the simplified handler:

```
hnd :: Something -> ServerT Raw Handler
hnd _ = serveDirectoryWith "a/b/c"
```

is equivalent to:

```
hnd _ = Tagged (staticApp "a/b/c")
```

and given that an `Application` is actually a `Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived`, this is the same as:

```
hnd _ = Tagged (\req resp -> staticApp "a/b/c" req resp)
```

or:

```
hnd Something{..} = Tagged $ \req resp -> do
  staticApp "a/b/c" req resp
```

where the `do`-block is running in the plain old `IO` monad.  In this form, it's now possible to do "normal" IO stuff, which is how I derived the short answer above.

`RawM` from version 0.20 doesn't gain you much here.  It maps `ServantT RawM Handler` to a modified version of an application:

```
Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> Handler ResponseReceived
                                                ^^^^^^^
                                                instead of IO
```

which adds the ability to perform `Handler` actions besides `IO`, namely signaling a specific `ServerError`.  If you had a custom `HandlerT`, it could be more useful.  It wouldn't make it any easier to write your `hnd`, though.